# How to group by and find new or disappearing items

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, comparison

I am trying to assess in a sales database whether the # of advertisements has changed.
The example dataframe I am using is as such:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"offer-id": [1,1,2,2,3,4,5], "date": ["2024-02-10","2024-02-11","2024-02-10","2024-02-11","2024-02-11","2024-02-11","2024-02-10"], "price": [30,10,30,30,20,25,20]})
```

And looks like the below:

[image: Dataframe]

I am now trying to get the # of items that were sold or newly added (I don't care which one, since once I have one the other should be failry easily computable).

E.g. in a perfect case the next piece of code tells me that on 10th of February 3 offers were online (ID 1, 2, and 5) and one was sold (ID 5)
Or alternatively, it tells me on 11th of February 4 offers are online, and 2 of them are new (from that, since I know the day before 5 were online I can also calculate that one must have sold)

Is there a simple way of doing this?
I have tried things like

```
df.groupby(['date'])["offer-id"].agg({'nunique'})
```

but they are missing the "comparison to previous" timestep component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could aggregate as a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
offers = df.groupby('date', sort=True)['offer-id'].agg(set)

date
2024-02-10       {1, 2, 5}
2024-02-11    {1, 2, 3, 4}
Name: offer-id, dtype: object
```

Then getting the [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) will give you the new items:

```
offers.diff()

date
2024-02-10       NaN
2024-02-11    {3, 4}
Name: offer-id, dtype: object
```

Or the sold items:

```
offers.diff(-1)

date
2024-02-10    {5}
2024-02-11    NaN
Name: offer-id, dtype: object
```

If you want the number of items, chain [`str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
offers.diff().str.len().fillna(0).convert_dtypes()

date
2024-02-10    0
2024-02-11    2
Name: offer-id, dtype: Int64
```

And to get those as new columns, [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['new'] = df['date'].map(offers.diff().str.len().fillna(0).convert_dtypes())
df['sold'] = df['date'].map(offers.diff(-1).str.len().fillna(0).convert_dtypes())

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   offer-id        date  price  new  sold
0         1  2024-02-10     30    0     1
1         1  2024-02-11     10    2     0
2         2  2024-02-10     30    0     1
3         2  2024-02-11     30    2     0
4         3  2024-02-11     20    2     0
5         4  2024-02-11     25    2     0
6         5  2024-02-10     20    0     1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Incredibly help- and insight-ful!